# Use keyword as C function parameter or C++ template argument

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to use just a plain, arbitrary keyword as a C function argument or a C++ template argument?

For example:

```
func(Random);
```

or

```
Class<Random>();
```

In this example, `Random` is not a predefined variable name, type name or Macro value.

Essentially, these values will be converted into a string but for the my purposes, I don't want to pass it as a string.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: The closest I can see would be an enum, given your requirements.

Comment: `Random` is not a keywordof C or C++. It seems like what you're searching for is an enum name.

Comment: You probably want to use `enum` or `enum class`.

Comment: Yes. I understand that `Random` is not a word. I was curious to see if it was possible to do the stringification, like in a C macro, in a C/C++ function or C++ template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, if you want, define some macro

```
#define KW(x)  #x
```

and then you are free to use

```
void func(const char *p);
func(KW(oi));
```

or

```
void func(std::string s);
func(KW(ciao));
```

... another option would be defining `func` as a macro, like:

```
#define func(a, x, b) realFunc(a, #x, b)
```

and then

```
void realFunc(int a, std::string s, double b);
func(3, arigato, 4.1);
```

...

Comment: This gains nothing over just writing `func("oi");` etc.

Comment: @MattMcNabb edited... but, yes, in the end, there is no real gain (except if one wants to map a variable to its name for debugging purposes...)